# I want to send the ids of selected items to another page

Tags: php, ajax

I've a cart page which previews items. I want to send ids of the selected items when the user update the size or the quantity of an item to another page using ajax. I've already done this but it is updating only one item not all items.

My HTML:

```
<select id="eachItemSize" class="eachItemSize" name="eachItemSize">
```

My Ajax:

```
$(document).on('change', '#eachItemSize', function(){
            var eachItemSize = $(this).find(":selected").val();
            $.ajax({
                url:"update.php?eachitemsize="+eachItemSize,
                method:"POST",
                data:{eachItemSize:eachItemSize},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                }
            });

            //   alert(eachItemSize);

        });
```

Comment: For multiselect it should be like this : <select id="eachItemSize" class="eachItemSize" name="eachItemSize[]" multiple>

Comment: when the user change the size i want to send the id of item which he changed

Comment: <form method="post" action="" id="<?=encrypt_decrypt("encrypt",$cartItemdID)?>_<?=$cartListCounter?>">

Comment: when u set select attr multiple then u will get the multiple select value otherwise u always get single value

Comment: it change only the last item even if i change the first item it overwrite the last item not the same item that i selected

Comment: pass the name of select like this name="eachItemSize[]"  its an array see my first comment